# Custom error message is not working laravel5.1 form request?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

Custom error message in form request class in not working, my form request class given below,

```
class FileRequest extends Request {

    protected $rules = [
        'title' => ['required', 'max:125'],
        'category_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:file_categories,id']
    ];
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules() {
        return $this->rules;
    }
    public function message() {
        return [
            "category_id.required" => 'Category required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Here when `category_id` is null, showing error message `category id is required` instead of `Category required` in laravel 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `messages`, not `message`.

Change

```
public function message()
```

to

```
public function messages()
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create any functions to change these messages. In the file `/resources/lang/en/validation.php` you can add translations for the field names you are using in the `attributes` array.

In your case, you would do the following:

```
return [
    'attributes' => [
        'category_id' => 'Category'
    ],

];
```

Now, whenever the `category_id` doesn't pass the validations, the error message will display this simply as `Category`.

Comment: this is another method doing globally.. is it possible to using this message function?